# Clean or replace water inlet assembly on LG dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

I broke the drain hose of my LG dishwasher (LDS-4821-st) right as the garbage disposal inlet, so I moved the dishwasher out to install a new drain hose assembly. I found the water inlet assembly to have what looks to me mold or something gross in it. I see several videos online on how to remove and replace, but I don’t see anything about cleaning the inside. Can these clear plastic boxes be opened easily, so I can clean it? Or am I just better off replacing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to disassemble that, but I would suggest doing an empty load with a few cups of bleach. Maybe once a month or so. I would assume it is dirty water side and not entering back into the machine during a wash cycle. If so, the mold may not be a huge issue. But try the bleach trick with maybe the hottest setting the machine can do. Do this a few times in a row (I know water waste) but if its not causing any other issues with the machine, i would just run the bleach and monitor it. Why replace it if its not broke!!!

Comment: white vinegar is also a good mold removal agent. I applaud the recommendation to purge before attempting a repair.